# How to Generate Serial from base 000001 to 999999 or LEFT padding?

Tags: c#, ms-access, loops

How to Implement LEFT Padding in Code or Query.

```
FROM        TO  
1           000001
2           000002 
10          000010   
110         000110 
1110        001110 
99999       099999
```

I am using MS Access 2007.

Thanks in Regards..

Comment: Could you be any less clear? Perhaps try wording your question in one or two sentences instead of copying and pasting.

Comment: This is a presentation-layer issue (most likely), so should most likely be handled in code and not in SQL at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to format a number as a string with leading zeros, you can use the `d6` format:

```
int i = 200;
Console.Write(i.ToString("d6")); // prints 000200
```

Example: http://ideone.com/fScd9

Comment: This is supported in Access 2007?

Comment: @Brettski - Probably not, I'm not sure. In my defense, The question is tagged C# and asks for a solution "in Code or Query" (this is the code). It isn't quick clear if the OP is writing a VBA script, and SQL query, or an Office extension.

Comment: It seems to me that this is the best answer, because it is a display issue.

Answer (score 2):

in VBA, use the `Format$` function (drop the dollar sign if you are using variants), and use "000000" for the format string.

Answer (score 1):

format$(serial, "000000")
or
format(serial, "000000")

This will format the string to six digits using zeros where there are no leading numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `right("000000" & serial,6)`.  Using `Format` is more elegant, however if you are running this on really large datasets or ODBC linked datasets it can be quite a bit slower.

```
SELECT [serial], right("000000" & [serial],6) AS [PaddedSerial]
FROM Table1
```